# Zero Morphism: Definition

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Given an abelian category $\mathbb{A}$.
There are numerous definitions of zero morphism:

For every pair of objects $X,Y\in\mathbb{A}$
there is a morphism $0_{YX}:X\to Y$ such that..

**Factorization**

.. it factors through a zero object $0_{YX}=0_{Y0}0_{0X}$.

**Composition**

..it annihilates morhphisms $0_{YX}f_{XA}=0_{YA}$ and $g_{BY}0_{YX}=0_{BX}$.

**Addition**

..it acts as the identity $f_{YX}+0_{YX}=f_{YX}$.

Now are these zero morphisms the same?

Comment: Don't forget the morphism that factors through the zero object. That's a zero morphism too.

Comment: Good point, I will add this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a zero object $0$. It's easy to prove that the composition $X\to0\to Y$ is independent of the zero object (because if $0'$ is another one there is a unique isomorphism $0\to0'$).

Let's take as definition of zero morphism $X\to Y$ one that factors through the chosen zero object. Such a morphism is unique (easy proof), so we can denote it by $0_{XY}$.

Consider now $f\colon X\to Y$ and do the composition $0_{YZ}f$; then we have
$$
X\xrightarrow{f}Y\mathrel{\underbrace{\to 0\to}_{0_{YZ}}}Z
$$
so $0_{YZ}f$ factors through the zero object; hence $0_{YZ}f=0_{XZ}$.

Conversely, if $Y\xrightarrow{z}Z$ has the property that $zf=0$, for all $f$ with codomain $Y$, then, in particular it does for $Y\xrightarrow{1}Y$, so $z$ must factor through the zero object.

Similarly (or by duality) on the other side.

In order to show that $0_{XY}$ acts as the neutral element for sum of morphisms, recall how sum of morphisms is defined (or characterized) via a suitable diagram.

Comment: I just know that we require addition to be bilinear over composition. But how to continue from there?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the converse check: Shouldn't it read "... $Y\stackrel{zy}{\to}Z$ has the property that zy f=yx ..."?

Comment: @FreeziiS If $z$ is “absorbing on the right”, then it is the zero morphism. What should $y$ be?

Comment: I just found on a blog by Qiaochu Yuan that zero morphisms in the sense of the definition **Composition** are unique.

Comment: I guess the above converse check is assuming that $0$ is the morphism that factors through the zero object? But that is not the correct assumption for showing equivalence of the definitions!

Comment: @FreeziiS The converse assumes $z\colon Y\to Z$ is a morphism such that $zf=0$; you need some definition of a zero morphism, don't you?

Comment: Well, yes, but the definition is that the system of zero morphisms satisfies the composition property. Not more!

Comment: But that problem is solved by checking that such systems are unique supposed they exist.

Comment: However, more interesting: Why are such zero morphisms the identity on addition?

Comment: @FreeziiS: this question was asked here two days ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2207898/144221

Comment: @DonAlejo: Great thanks!! Now I just checked that having zero morphism and having neutral morphisms is equivalent and that they agree.

Answer (score 3):

*Yes they are*, and in fact I would propose a *third* description which needs no further existence proof and allows for quick verification of the properties that you mentioned:

> **Definition:** For any two $X,Y$, the zero morphism is the morphism $X\to 0\to Y$, where the morphisms $X\to 0$ and $Y\to 0$ used are the unique morphisms (since $0$ is both terminal and initial).

Starting from this, do you want to try to show that it implies your properties?

Comment: Yes exactly, but unfortunately it didn't seem to work.. can you help me?